# Jmeter removes / from the request url path

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, url-validation

I have a request which looks like http://example.com/content//testid. When Jmeter making request to it automatically removes // after 'content' in the request url and the requested url looks like http://example.com/content/testid. Due to this invalid url, the request ends up in error.

Please let me know if anybody faced this kind of error and the way to rectify it.

Comment: It worked by escaping the // in the request

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with JMeter 5.3 on MacOS Catalina version 10.15.6

Please check the values in the HTTP Request

[image]

Following request was created by JMeter when the test was executed

[image]